# How do I get a copy of an ESTA if I have mislaid my copy?

Tags: usa, esta

I visited New York last year in September on an ESTA, but I have mislaid my copy. How do I get another copy as I am travelling again to New York in the next couple of weeks?

Many thanks.

Comment: It's not a visa, and you don't need a printed copy of it anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Anecdotal evidence: I once got asked for a copy of my ESTA on Germanwings (though they finally let me pass without one - but the didn't seem happy).  They were fairly insistive, so it probably doesn't hurt to have it with you.

Comment: @npl What Airport? Would be interesting to know what check-in Company it was, as that is grounds for a complaint.

Comment: @Coke Cologne, about 2 years ago. Seems they usually check this at checkin in CGN, but this was a LH ticket from MUC with the 4U as an LH codeshare.  Apparently they were not used to seeing that ...  In any case, I'd rather get on the flight than successfully file a complaint :)

Comment: @npl AHS staff then (if you flew Germanwings). I do indeed have poor experience with them too (regarding other travel documentation stuff), not least in MUC

Comment: We also had this ecnounter once in Munich. We were forced to find a printer and print the ESTA, they wouldn't let us on otherwise (Icelandair).

Comment: @Coke This was the ground staff in CGN.

Comment: @npl Yeah, AHS operate at several Airports, and that is the one handling Eurowings (formerly Germanwings) at CGN.

Answer (score 13):

You [don't need a paper copy of your ESTA authorization](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e3s1#TRAVEL):

> ## Traveling with an ESTA
>
> ### Do I need to bring a printout or digital copy of my travel authorization to the airport?
>
> No. DHS will be able to communicate a traveler's ESTA status to the carriers. However, DHS recommends that travelers print out the travel authorization application response in order to maintain a record of their traveler authorization application number and to have confirmation of their ESTA status.
>
> U.S. regulation does NOT require a Visa Waiver Program (VWP) traveler to present a printed copy of the ESTA authorization page in order to travel. However, it is recommended that you print a copy for your records. If you applied for ESTA and you have forgotten your application number, you may retrieve the application through the ESTA website by entering the applicants name, date of birth, passport number and passport issuing country.

As mentioned above, you can nonetheless get one at [the official ESTA site](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e1s1).

Obligatory pedantry: ESTA is not a visa, at least in the terminology of the United States.  It is an authorization that allows you to travel to the US and apply for entry under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP).  (Since the VWP is all about relieving people of a visa requirement, it would be illogical and counterproductive to call ESTA a visa.)

As noted by [jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/jpatokal) in a helpful comment, a printed copy may nonetheless be useful in some situations, particularly with the airline:

> The *US* does not require a printed copy of the ESTA; however, airlines may still ask for it, particularly if you have a complicated itinerary and your first flight is not to the US.

(emphasis in original)

Comment: The *US* does not require a printed copy of the ESTA; however, airlines may still ask for it, particularly if you have a complicated itinerary and your first flight is not to the US.